# UWP XAML How to handle Unhandle exception

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a listview and I insert the item into listview. Between inserting of item my application crash and how unhandled exception and error "incorrect parameter". I don't understand where exactly this crash. How can I go deep in XAML unhandled exception?

```
                var messages = obj.Messages;
                messages.Reverse();
                AddMessagesToMessageList(openChatData, messages);
                if (obj.IsFirstTime && MessageList.Count > 0)
                {
                    ChatListSelectedIndex = -1;
                    SendFullAck();
                    await ScrollIntoViewWithDelayAsync(MessageList.Count - 1);
                }
                else if (MessageList.Count > 0)
                {
                    await ScrollIntoViewWithDelayAsync(messages.Count - 1);
                }

                if (obj.Messages.Count < 10)
                {
                    _isNoMoreChats = true;
                }
                CheckOpenChatDataRemainingMessages();
                _isDirty = false;



    private void AddMessagesToMessageList(AbstractChatData openChatData, 
    List<Message> messages)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("AddMessagesToMessageList Start", GetType().Name, false);
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                AddMessageToMessageList(openChatData, message, null);
            }
            ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("AddMessagesToMessageList End", GetType().Name, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ObjFactory.Instance.CreateLogger().Log("EX= " + ex.Message, GetType().Name);
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is most commonly caused when XAML tree is being constructed. I would suggest trying to comment out parts of the XAML code and run the app to locate the problematic part. It is most likely caused by using a disallowed attribute or nesting.

You cannot dive deeper into the exception details as it happens in generated code, however I agree it would be useful if it were more descriptive.

You may post your XAML code if you want further help investigating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replay.. i will try to comment code in XAML and try...i there any tools that helps us in XAML issues?

Comment: I usually find the commenting approach the quickest. Not sure if there are better alternatives in this case. You can also try commenting out the code-behind code, just to make sure the problem doesn't happen there. In general, the unhandled error occurs most often when the page constructor failed to finish.